# Jsp page is not showing images on page fetching from a folder placed on WebRoot\file folder

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsp, tomcat, servlets

My Images name A(1),A(2).......A(n) is placed into root/file folder.
Tomcat is telling, image can not be displayed, it has error, if we giving the image URL in address bar...
This is  Show.jsp page.

```
<%

        String x = getServletContext().getContextPath().toString();


        x=request.getServerName();
        int y=request.getServerPort();
        x=z+""+y+dir;



        File f = new File(x);

        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            String[] fileList = f.list();
            //out.println("Directory of " + x + "<br>");
            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {

                File f1 = new File( fileList[i]);
                if (f1.isDirectory()) {

// to Show it is a directory
out.println(fileList[i] + " is a Directory<br>");
                } else {

                    out.print("<br>");

        out.print( fileList[i]); // file name list
    %>

    <img src="<%out.print(fileList[i]);%>" /> // image URL Dynamically

    <br />

    <%
        }
            }
        } else {
            out.println("<BR>");
        }
    %>
```